# The value of int is based on the _____ coding scheme

Tags: c++

This is a homework question I just can't seem to get correct. It is related to a C++ programming course. The question is given below, fill in the blank.

The char and int data types have a direct equivalence, with the value of the int being based on the _________ coding scheme.

Comment: I'm a bit amazed at how poorly worded that question is.

Comment: How would you recommend I reword this question, as this was my first posting and I was trying to keep it simple and straight to the point. If it's seen as unhelpful I'm willing to delete it. Thanks for the input, I can agree.

Comment: I'm referring to the homework question. Did your professor/teacher give you that exact question?

Comment: The one used in the title was my own attempt to make a sensible question, but as for the one below in the description is word for word given by a professor as a question. I would of eventually guessed it correctly, but after 3 failed attempts I wanted someone else to take a look.

Comment: I would complain to the teacher, or shall we say show them this thread 'for comment'.

Comment: As mentioned, I would inform the teacher that you think it's a very poorly worded question. I feel bad for the students who have to read this (it makes no sense).

Comment: I'll try to see where my teacher was coming from with this question, if it's from the book Starting out with C++ Early Objects, or wherever else. I will post here if I can get a credible explanation or revision.

Comment: If the question had said "...the value of the _char_  being based..." It would be somewhat better. And then get rid of the whole "direct equivalence" phrase.

Comment: I got feedback from my professor, he argued that "Given that the following is allowed:char a = 'A'; int ia = a; direct equivalence based on the ASCII coding scheme (as ia would have the value 65).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exam has asked a poorly-worded question! `char` and `int` do NOT have a direct equivalence - but a `char` can be *interpreted* as an `int`, *usually* using the "ASCII" coding scheme ("American Standard Code for Information Interchange"). But even that's not universal - there's also EBCDIC and others.

But try "ASCII".

#### Edit

According to the C standard, the character encoding doesn't have to be ASCII. But there are rules it has to follow:

1. The repesentations for '0' to '9' **must** be consecutive and in that order, to make calculations easy when converting to `int`.
2. The representations for 'A' to 'Z' **must** be ascending, to make calculations for sorting easy (note *not* necessarily consecutive - for example in EBCDIC they're not).
3. The representations for 'a' to 'z' **must** also adhere to the above rule, but also the difference between upper and lower case **must** be the same for every character (note that lower could come before upper).